# Inconsistency between timieit with number and timeit without a number

Tags: python, numpy, sympy, timeit

I've noticed that results change rapidly between running  timeit with the regular arugments and timeit with the argument number=1. Here is the example that I found.

```
import sympy as sp
import numpy as np
var = (sp.Symbol("x"), sp.Symbol("y"), sp.Symbol("z"))
x,y,z = var[0], var[1], var[2]
monos = np.array([1, z, y, x, z**2, y*z, y**2, x*z, x*y, x**2, z**3, y*z**2, y**2*z, y**3, x*z**2, x*y*z, x*y**2, x**2*z, x**2*y, x**3, z**4, y*z**3, y**2*z**2, y**3*z, y**4, x*z**3, x*y*z**2, x*y**2*z, x*y**3, x**2*z**2, x**2*y*z, x**2*y**2, x**3*z, x**3*y, x**4])
f = sp.lambdify(var, monos)
import testit
timeit.timeit("(f(2,3,4))", setup="from __main__ import f") 
#returns 2.0760600566864014
timeit.timeit("(f(2,3,4))", setup="from __main__ import f", number=1)
#returns 1.5974044799804688e-05
```

I'm using python2 version 2.7.12 and sympy version 1.2. What is going on here?

Comment: Well did you expect this function to work exactly the same regardless of the arguments you pass to it? Have you looked at the [corresponding docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/timeit.html#timeit.timeit)? What do they say about the number argument?

Answer (score 0):

Unlike the IPython %timeit, `timeit.timeit` returns the total time taken by all the runs. To get the time of an individual run, you have to divide by the number. You can also use `timeit.Timer(stmt).autorange()` (Python 3.6+ only), which picks a number of runs automatically.

I recommend using the IPython `%timeit` for timing. It only works interactively, but it's much easier to work with than the `timeit` module in the standard library.